# How do I find the field representation of a light source?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy

I'm trying to propagate a light source with cross-spectral density
$$W(x_1,x_2)=S_0\delta(x_1-x_2)$$
which is a completely incoherent light source. I want to find the field representation of the source (this value is usually called $U(x)$). Can I do this from the cross spectral density? If not, how can I find the value of $U(x)$ for an incoherent light source?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This cross-spectral density would have infinite spectral density $W(x,x)$, which is not plausible.

Propagation induces coherence, therefore I believe no field distribution over the source will give rise to a "completely incoherent" radiation.